# Tag synonyms for Bittorrent

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

For good or ill, we'll probably continue to get questions [like this one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/727/using-torrent-via-tor) about Bittorrent and Tor.

Several questions are marked as [torrents](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torrents) while others are marked as [bittorrent](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent). I propose making [torrents](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torrents) a synonym of [bittorrent](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent).

Any thoughts? Vote [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/tags/bittorrent/synonyms).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote and probably few other people do. What about a filesharing tag? It's not just torrent that is unwanted on Tor, also emule and such?

Comment: People could add a filesharing tag, but that's not synonymous with Bittorrent IMO. We should attempt to answer BT / other file sharing questions (assuming they're on topic and about Tor) properly, even if the answer is bad for the Tor network (though, of course, you could always say, "but please don't do this" in your answer)